# Angular 2 Heroes Tutorial missing repeat values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow the Angular 2 "Tour of Heroes" Tutorial, but I've run into a problem. After declaring the "onSelect" method for the (click) event, the list of 'let hero of heroes' goes blank. This is what I have so far:

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MyComponent} from './my-component';



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class = 'heroes'>
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)='onSelect(hero)'>
                <span class='badge'>{{hero.id}}</span>
                {{hero.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
        <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
        <div>
            <label>name: </label><input [(ngModel)] ='selectedHero.name' placeholder = 'name'>
        </div>

        `,

    directives: [MyComponent]

    styles: [`
      .selected {
        background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
        color: white;
      }
      .heroes {
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 15em;
      }
      .heroes li {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin: .5em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        height: 1.6em;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .heroes li.selected:hover {
        background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
        color: white;
      }
      .heroes li:hover {
        color: #607D8B;
        background-color: #DDD;
        left: .1em;
      }
      .heroes .text {
        position: relative;
        top: -3px;
      }
      .heroes .badge {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: small;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
        background-color: #607D8B;
        line-height: 1em;
        position: relative;
        left: -1px;
        top: -4px;
        height: 1.8em;
        margin-right: .8em;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
      }
      `]

})
export class AppComponent { 

    title = 'Tour of Heroes';

    public heroes = HEROES;

    selectedHero: Hero;

    function onSelect(hero: Hero) {
        selectedHero: hero;
    }

}



export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celertitas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Megneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Rubberman' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }

];
```

The errors I'm getting on the terminal:

> app/app.component.ts(28,2): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> app/app.component.ts(87,2): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A
>   constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
>
> app/app.component.ts(91,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement
>   expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error stack trace tells you:

1. Add a comma after `directives: [MyComponent],`
2. Remove the `function` keyword from your `onSelect` function declaration.
3. Assign the `hero` variable to `this.selectedHero` instead of just `selectedHero` in your `onSelect` function.

Note that even if you'll do all these, when running the code you won't see the list of heroes, as there is an extra step you should implement from the tutorial for the list to be displayed properly. So, fix all these issues, then go further in your tutorial and everything will work.

Comment: Thank you iulian, that helped a lot. Just to expand my knowledge, how come the *ngIf was necessary to display the heroes objects initially in the list?

Answer (score 1):

My guess based on the errors you get is:

```
- 1 add comma after directives array declaration on line 28
- 2 remove 'function' before your onSelect on line 87
- 3 assign value to var selectedHero like this on line 88 
        selectedHero = hero;
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the fixes but still nothing is appearing in the list or where the selectedHero's properties should be displayed. The terminal is no longer displaying any errors. I've added a picture to the original post.

Comment: hmm.. can't see anything attached

Comment: Yeah, iulian's post fixed the problem for me before I got a chance to post it. Thank you for your help! I had to write an "*ngIf='selectedHero' statement in a new div, although I'm not sure why the page wouldn't initialize with empty fields for just the selectedHero instead of having all the 'hero' objects missing.